# IE11 не проигрывает длинные mp3 файлы

Tags: аудио, text-to-speech, ie11

Имеется несколько тегов audio на странице вида

```
<audio src="https://polly.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/speech?OutputFormat=mp3&amp;SampleRate=16000..."></audio>
```

Так вот ситуация в том, что короткие файлы проигрываются без проблем, а длинные просто не воспроизводятся. Проблему нагуглить не смог. Посоветуйте куда хоть копать.

В консоли ошибок нет
Файл с сервера получает, но не проигрывает
В остальных браузерах всё ок, проблема только в IE

Comment: В инструменты браузера, смотреть мониторинг сети и консоль ошибок?

Comment: Не видя шапок, сигнатур и логов - ничего нельзя сказать.

Comment: В консоли никаких ошибок нет

Comment: Какую продолжительность подразумеваете под короткими и длинными аудиофайлами? И было бы полезно увидеть URLы примеров mp3 файлов, если это не секрет.

Comment: @STY короткие - до 10 секунд примерно, все что больше не проигрывается. урлы генерятся AWS SDK for JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Одна из возможных причин - кодек трека, не поддерживаемый IE, см. таблицу: http://htmlbook.ru/html/audio

Так же не заметил в вашем примере ни аттрибута autoplay для автоматического воспроизведения, ни controls для ручного.

P.S. [Небольшое демо](https://jsfiddle.net/styfrombrest/k9o3g476/), трехминутный трек успешно воспроизводится в паре с двумя короткими в IE11(11.0.9600):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <audio src="http://www.freshly-ground.com/misc/music/20060826%20-%20Armstrong.mp3">Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.</audio>
    <audio loop src="http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/_mp3/walking.mp3">Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.</audio>
    <audio loop src="http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/_mp3/rain.mp3">Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.</audio>
</body>
</html>
```